# Перевод строки форматирования даты из одной локализации в другую

Tags: windows, delphi, winapi, devexpress

DevExpress PropertyEditor хранит строку форматирования в виде строки, из-за чего нет универсальности в поддержке формата заданного в Windows.

Может есть какая-то WinAPI, для трансляции строки форматирования из определённой локилизации (всегда константа) в пользовательскую (типа LOCALE_SYSTEM_DEFAULT)?

TransFormat(LANG_RUSSIAN, LOCALE_SYSTEM_DEFAULT);

Например для 'dd.MM.yyyy' при LOCALE_SYSTEM_DEFAULT = LANG_ENGLISH получим 'yyyy-MM-dd'

Можно конечно самому написать, но может есть стандартное решение для этого, чтобы не пытаться учесть все возможные языки самому...

Answer (score 3):

Если речь о форматировании даты/времени, то это делается просто:

1. Переводим строку с известной локалью в `TDateTime`;
2. Переводим `TDateTime` в строку, используя системную локаль.

---

```
var
  VDate: TDateTime;
  VStr: string;
begin
  VDate := StrToDate('24.07.2023', TFormatSettings.Create('ru-RU'));
  VStr := DateToStr(VDate);
  Writeln(VStr)
end;
```

UPD:

Получить строку форматирования даты:

- для текущей локали: `FormatSettings.ShortDateFormat`
- для произвольной локали: `TFormatSettings.Create('en-US').ShortDateFormat`

Конвертировать же именно строку форматирования из одной локали в другую, не имеет никакого смысла, т.к. все строки форматирования для всех локалей у вас всегда под рукой. Просто выбирайте нужную.

Comment: я напрасно примером с конкретной датой ввёл в заблуждение, наверное. Речь не о форматировании даты, а о перестройке строки форматирования под другую локаль

Comment: @Isaev строки форматирования **чего**? Таки даты или чего-то другого?

Comment: @Isaev Строку форматирования даты для текущей локали можно получить вот так: `FormatSettings.ShortDateFormat` и никаких функций "перевода" вообще не требуется.

Comment: @zen даты да, перечитайте внимательно вопрос. Сторонняя библиотека, строка форматирования на входе, все преобразования внутри библиотеки, на них мы повлиять не можем. Если пишите код в одной локали, он не работает в другой, т.к. дата не может быть преобразована! Потому нужно преобразование именно строки форматирования

Comment: @Isaev Обновил ответ.

Comment: попробую ещё раз)

XComponent.Property.FormatString = 'dd.mm.yyyy', 
это записано в dfm, дату по этой строке генерирует компонент. 
если в локали пользователя 'yyyy-mm-dd', он хочет видеть данные в своём привычном формате, а не в 'dd.mm.yyyy', потому строку форматирования нужно преобразовать под текущую локаль. Но мы не можем просто взять ShortDateFormat например, т.к. если было указано только 'mm.yyyy', то нужно и вывести только 'yyyy-mm', потому необходимо именно преобразование строки форматирования!

Comment: @Isaev На сколько мне известно, для произвольного формата универсального решения нет. Используя TFormatSettings в нужной локали, вы можете определить в какой последовательности идут компоненты даты, какой используется разделитель, и уже потом руками сконструировать нужный формат.